# Update field with another field's value in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `t1` with the following fields in its schema

```
_id, field1, field1
```

I want set `field2`'s value `field1` like sql:

```
update t1 set field1=field2;
```

How do I do it in MongoDB?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field/

Answer (score 46):

Good and bad news here.

Bad news is that AFAIK you can't do it with a single update() call - mongo doesn't support referring to current object in update.

Good news is that there are other ways to do it, e.g. you can run a forEach loop:

```
db.item.find(conditions...).snapshot().forEach( function (doc) {
  doc.field1 = doc.field2; 
  db.item.save(doc); 
});
```

You can run forEach in the admin shell ('mongo' command), or through some of the methods of your specific driver (e.g. in PHP I'd expect it to work with mongodb.execute() as described in here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php)

Comment: Because a call to save() is being made within the forEach loop, the cursor will get messed up and the function will potentially get called multiple times for each document. The solution is to call snapshot() before the foreach: db.item.find(blah).snapshot().forEach()

Comment: Thanks for that. I was not aware of the snapshot() requirement for this to work as intended. TBH I was taken aback at first that a function called "forEach" doesn't guarantee what its name is implying (because it's similar to what you can find in collections libraries in programming languages), but then again, I understand that there may be plenty of reasons to do that.

Comment: There's no atomic way of doing this? This solution doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: @JakubP.: If i have 10 fields in my document, and i have to update only a single field, should i use save() for this...the updated value will be calculated from old value

Comment: if you have enough space on your hard disk, consider saving to a new collection, then drop and rename. Dropping and renaming was pretty fast.

Comment: Is this still true with mongodb 3.0?

Comment: Use caution with this approach when used in conjunction with a projection.  Specifically, the updated document is saved with only the fields that where part of the projection.

Comment: @tacone You can only do the "drop and rename" strategy if you have some way to guarantee you don't have new data coming in during the interim, or if you have a way to sync that data after the fact in the "good" form.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham of course and the same applies to all the answers in this page. MongoDB does not have transactions and atomicity is guaranteed only at single document level.

Comment: @tacone True. If you have an advantage of running on downtime, both solutions give you similar results, but drop-and-rename might be simpler to know that you're "done". If you have a hot sync, then doing it in-place might be a simpler solution, cause you might be able to fix the data source, then loop until it runs clean. Maybe. I haven't done the hot-sync in production before :) Just wanted to point out the syncing issue, really.

Comment: @JoelHarris maybe you or OP knows, but really anyone reading this: Did snapshot() get deprecated at some point. I got an error, and I can't find any mention of it in the 4.0 documentation, but I also don't see any mention of its deprecation in release notes.

Comment: Comparing the 3.2 documentation to the 4.0 documentation, it seems 4.0 does not use snapshot, and instead you must specify an index using hint()...I am brand new to mongo, so I don't want to spread misinformation, but I am curious to know if this is accurate.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#cursor-snapshot

Comment: For those reading this in year >= 2022: .snapshot() method is not in mongodb API anymore. But you can use .toArray() instead.

Answer (score 14):

Starting from version 3.4, we can use the `$addFields` aggregation pipeline operator to this without client side processing which is the most efficient way.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { "field2": "$field1" }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

---

Prior to version 3.4 we need to iterate the `Cursor` object and use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to add the new field with the existing "field1" value. You need to do this using "bulk" operation for maximum efficiency.

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) and its [associated methods,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) thus from 3.2 upwards you need to use the [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method.

```
var requests = [];
db.collection.find({}, { 'field1': 1 } ).snapshot().forEach(document => { 
    requests.push( { 
        'updateOne': {
            'filter': { '_id': document._id },
            'update': { '$set': { 'field2': document.field1 } }
        }
    });
    if (requests.length === 1000) {
        //Execute per 1000 operations and re-init
        db.collection.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
    }
});

if(requests.length > 0) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

---

From version 2.6 to 3.0 you can use the `Bulk` API.

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.find({}, { 'field1': 1 }).snapshot().forEach(function(document) { 
    bulk.find({ '_id': document._id }).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'field2': document.field1 }
    });
    count++;
    if(count%1000 === 0) {
        // Excecute per 1000 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// clean up queues
if(count > 0) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: In my tests, I found the aggregation method to be MUCH faster. My sample data had 150K documents that took 5 seconds to reshape, whereas the .foreach methods took ~1.5 minutes.   What are caveats/gotchas to be considered when going with the aggregation approach?

Comment: `aggregate` with `out` is not sutable, if `match` needed: final collection will contain only matched documents.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done through:

```
db.nameOfCollection.find().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.nameOfCollection.update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    field2: elem.field1
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: You failed your copy-paste of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14423151/2054072

Comment: yes, @Deejay if you find an answer somewhere else in StackOverflow, please refer a link instead, that will help us in participating cross-questioning with the teacher himself/herself.