# MongoDB: Updating documents using data from the same document

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of documents, each with lat and lon properties (among others).

```
{ 'lat': 1, 'lon': 2, someotherdata [...] } 
{ 'lat': 4, 'lon': 1, someotherdata [...] }
[...]
```

I want to modify it so that it looks like this:

```
{ 'coords': {'lat': 1, 'lon': 2}, someotherdata [...]} 
{ 'coords': {'lat': 4, 'lon': 1}, someotherdata [...]}
[...]
```

So far I've got this:

```
db.events.update({}, {$set : {'coords': {'lat': db.events.lat, 'lon': db.events.lon}}}, false, true)
```

But it treats the *db.events.lat* and *db.events.lon* as strings. How can I reference the document's properties?

Cheers.

Comment: There is feature request for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/) operator (introduced a month after this question was posted) makes it really easy to do these kinds of things where you don't need to modify the values.

**Insert some test documents**

```
db.events.insert({ 'lat': 1, 'lon': 2, someotherdata: [] })
db.events.insert({ 'lat': 4, 'lon': 1, someotherdata: [] })
```

**use the `$rename` operator**

```
db.events.update({}, {$rename: {'lat': 'coords.lat', 'lon': 'coords.lon'}}, false, true)
```

**Results**

```
db.events.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5113c82dd28c4e8b79971add"),
    "coords" : {
        "lat" : 1,
        "lon" : 2
    },
    "someotherdata" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5113c82ed28c4e8b79971ade"),
    "coords" : {
        "lat" : 4,
        "lon" : 1
    },
    "someotherdata" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 214):

**Update:** If all you have to do is change the structure of a document without changing the values, see [gipset's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755086/332100) for a nice solution.

---

According to a (now unavailable) comment on the [Update documentation page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/), you cannot reference the current document's properties from within an `update()`.

You'll have to iterate through all the documents and update them like this:

```
db.events.find().snapshot().forEach(
  function (e) {
    // update document, using its own properties
    e.coords = { lat: e.lat, lon: e.lon };

    // remove old properties
    delete e.lat;
    delete e.lon;

    // save the updated document
    db.events.save(e);
  }
)
```

Such a function can also be used in a map-reduce job or a server-side `db.eval()` job, depending on your needs.

Comment: As per this comment on a similar question, I discovered that failing to snapshot() your find results, will throw the cursor into an infinite loop in some circumstances.
[update field with another field's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606657/how-can-i-update-field-with-another-fields-value#comment15682010_4260176)

Try 

    `db.events.find().snapshot().forEach(`
    `// ..function goes here`
    `)`

Comment: @AshleyRaiteri Thanks, I've included the call to `snapshot()` in the answer. Good catch :)

Comment: Why do you have to do `events.save()` inside the `forEach` block? Why not do `events.update()` in the same place?

Comment: This was very helpfull. I saved them in a new collection `db.event_new.save()` and then renamed them `db.event.renameCollection("event_old")` and `db.event_new.renameCollection("event")`, so that it gets replaced, but if any error ocurres it dosen't affect the original data.

Comment: First want to reiterate merlinpatt's comment: why not use an update instead? Does it matter? Secondly, I ran into problems trying to use snapshot. I am new to mongo and don't want to lead people astray, but from what I can tell, in Mongo 4.0 snapshot is gone and now you must use hint. If this is wrong please let me know: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#cursor-snapshot

Comment: @AlbertRothman, For mongo 4.0 use `.hint({_id: 1})` instead of `.snapshot()`.

Comment: Beautiful answer. What is the difference in performance between a query in a `updateMany` and this?

Comment: DEPRECATED since Mongo 3.6 http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/deprecated-list.html

Answer (score 6):

[Neils answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/4807889). Just to let people know you cannot run this on a large database if you are lets say doing it remote shell like Robomongo. You will need to ssh into your actual server's mongo shell. Also you could also do this if you would rather do an Update.

```
db.Collection.find({***/ possible query /***}).toArray().forEach(
  function(obj){
    obj.item = obj.copiedItem;
    obj.otherItem = obj.copiedItem;
    obj.thirdItem = true;
    obj.fourthItem = "string";
    db.Collection.update({_id: obj._id}, obj);
  }
);
```

Comment: Is this just a comment on the answer posted by Niels van der Rest?

Comment: It is a comment but also wanted to post a more descriptive answer than you can leave in the add comments section. I also wanted to post the code that I used based on his answer so if people were to lazy to go look up those links than here is a working model. Of course only works on the server. or in a remote shell if you only need to update  <101 documents. Some people might not see "save" as the best operation to use.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are OK with creating a copy of the data, the aggregation framework can be used as an alternative here.  You also have the option to do more to the data if you wish using other operators, but the only one you need is `$project`.  It's somewhat wasteful in terms of space, but may be faster and more appropriate for some uses.  To illustrate, I'll first insert some sample data into the `foo` collection:

```
db.foo.insert({ 'lat': 1, 'lon': 2, someotherdata : [1, 2, 3] })
db.foo.insert({ 'lat': 4, 'lon': 1, someotherdata : [4, 5, 6] })
```

Now, we just use `$project` to rework the `lat` and `lon` fields, then send them to the `newfoo` collection:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project : {_id : "$_id", "coords.lat" : "$lat", "coords.lon" : "$lon", "someotherdata" : "$someotherdata" }},
    { $out : "newfoo" }
])
```

Then check `newfoo` for our altered data:

```
db.newfoo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544548a71b5cf91c4893eb9a"), "someotherdata" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "coords" : { "lat" : 1, "lon" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544548a81b5cf91c4893eb9b"), "someotherdata" : [ 4, 5, 6 ], "coords" : { "lat" : 4, "lon" : 1 } }
```

Once you are happy with the new data, you can then use the [`renameCollection()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) command to drop the old data and use the new data under the old name:

```
> db.newfoo.renameCollection("foo", true)
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544548a71b5cf91c4893eb9a"), "someotherdata" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "coords" : { "lat" : 1, "lon" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544548a81b5cf91c4893eb9b"), "someotherdata" : [ 4, 5, 6 ], "coords" : { "lat" : 4, "lon" : 1 } }
```

One last note - until [SERVER-7944](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7944) is completed you can't do the equivalent of a snapshot by hinting the `_id` index as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/1148648) and so you can end up hitting a document more than once if activity elsewhere causes it to move.  Since you are inserting the `_id` field in this example, any such occurrence would cause a unique key violation, so you will not end up with dupes, but you might have an "old" version of a document.  As always, check your data thoroughly before dropping it, and preferably take a backup.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Mongo script to manipulate data on the fly. It works for me!

I use this script to correct my address data.

Example of current address: "No.12, FIFTH AVENUE,".

I want to remove the last redundant comma, the expected new address ""No.12, FIFTH AVENUE".

```
var cursor = db.myCollection.find().limit(100);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var currentDocument = cursor.next();

  var address = currentDocument['address'];
  var lastPosition = address.length - 1;

  var lastChar = address.charAt(lastPosition);

  if (lastChar == ",") {

    var newAddress = address.slice(0, lastPosition);


    currentDocument['address'] = newAddress;

    db.localbizs.update({_id: currentDocument._id}, currentDocument);

  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the CLI? I think you have to pull the values out first and assign the value into a variable. Then run your update command.

Or (I haven't tried) remove 'db' from the string. `events.lat` and `events.lon` If it works, you will still have multiple values, the old values for "lat" and "lon" and the new array you created.