# Mongodb - update partial number of documents

Tags: mongodb

it is possible in Mongodb to limit the number of documents that can be updated in one shot?

I have a list of item order by insertion date (ie. by _id), I just want to update the (example) 5 oldest one.

I can retrieve the inform I want

```
db.mycoll.find({}).limit(5)
```

I can update one (and therefore cycle on the results of the previous query) or all (or using a combination)

```
db.mycoll.update({"_id" : ObjectId("4f672a5175fa1c01c100001d")}, {$set: {'b' : 'test'}}, false, true)
db.mycoll.update({}, {$set: {'b' : 'test'}}, false, true)
```

But I could not pass a criteria with a limit on the update request.
Any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can look this: [how-to-limit-number-of-updating-documents-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590890/how-to-limit-number-of-updating-documents-in-mongodb)

> Unfortunately the workaround you have is the only way to do it AFAIK. There is a boolean flag multi which will either update all the matches (when true) or update the 1st match (when false).

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, that unfortunately was my impression as well.

Comment: Is this still the case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

First get all records you want to update

```
var mycolls = db.mycoll.find({}).limit(5)
```

Then, map ids of these records

```
var mycollIDs = mycolls.map(x=>x._id)
```

Update all of these records using updateMany

```
db.mycolls.updateMany({_id:{$in:mycollIDs}},{set:{UPDATE DATA}})
```

Hope this could help!

Comment: Will this work with 12k ids I wonder?