# MongoDB update using limit and skip

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In Mongoose, I would need to do the following in the quickest possible way:

1. find documents by a query
2. use limit() and skip()
3. update a field in all the found records with the same value

what do you suggest?

Comment: do you want to update a field in all the found records with same value?

Comment: Yes, I update them with the same value

Comment: I can recommend this friend's method. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67951656/12829430)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get records and then get id's of all the records into one array and then 
  update them using `$in`

```
async function someAsyncFunction(){ 

    let foundData= await collection.find(query).skip().limit();
    let IDs=[];

    foundData.forEach(element=>{
     IDs.push(element._id);
       });

   return Collection.update(
                     {_id: { $in: IDs}}, 
                     { $set: {"fieldToUpdate": "value"}},
                     { multi: true }
                     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async updateRecordFunction(()=>{ 
    return await Collection.update({_id: { $in: await collection.find(query, {_id:1}).skip().limit().lean()?.map((data)=> data?._id)}}, 
                         { $set: {"fieldToUpdate": "value"}},
                         { multi: true }
                         );
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**