# Spring MongoTemplate updateMulti with Limit?

Tags: java, mongodb, limit, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data's MongoTemplate to update multiple documents with a single query. I need to be able to limit the number of documents I update per call. For reasons unclear to me the limit isn't working:

```
Query query = new Query(
    Criteria.where( "foo" ).is( bar )
    .and( "status" ).is( 1 ) );
query.limit( 10 );

Update update = new Update();
update.set( "status", 2 );

WriteResult result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti( query, update, "bazCollection" );

logger.info( result.getN() + " documents updated" );
```

result.getN() always returns the total number of documents that meet the Criteria and is ignoring the limit, and all documents meeting the criteria are modified.

Is there a reason this isn't working?

Is there a better approach to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6590890/1377224 . The answer will show you that you can't have a limited update. Update does this either for all documents or only the first one matching. If you want to have something like batch updates you need to catch a number of documents and update them on your own.

Comment: Unfortunate. I had hopes that MongoTemplate had some capability beyond that of the CLI to limit updates.

Comment: As you can see in the sources: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L938 this is just a invocation of the drivers update function, and thus same constraints apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use an updateMulti with limit but how to make atomic update status on a limited set of documents?

I used the following pattern to avoid concurrent write issue (concurrent change status more than one time on a given document):

- `find` target document id's to update using limit and using status condition
- `updateMulti` with target document id's and status as condition : target doc ids may have been already updated by concurrent thread so we need to set status as condition here again. This query sets also an updateTime in an update field
- `find` updated document id's : rely on document id's + updateTime.

Please let me know if there is a better solution / pattern to do that.