# How can i update all object in an array without id at MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I call the Elements with find() method and after than i want to update all. For example:

```
db.collection.find().limit(10).update({$set: {'column' : 'value'}});
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply update to every document in collection, use `{multi:true}` option

```
db.collection.update({},{$set: {'column' : 'value'}},{multi:true});
```

For more detail, see [collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)

However, if you want to update selected number of documents, you'll be taking longer route.

```
db.collection.find().limit(10).forEach(function(o){
    o.column = some_value; // replace some_value with real one.
    db.collection.update({_id:o._id},o);
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i got this error: db.collection.find(...).limit(...).update is not a function:

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way. I'm sorry I pasted your command as it is. try now.

Comment: @saleem, OP is asking for multi update with limit.  The update you have there will update every document in the collection, and is not correct syntax either since the first argument should be query selector, not what to update

Comment: Well, to define limit there must be some condition. I don't think limit is applicable on update they way it's applicable on `find.`

Comment: However, only way to limit, is to call `find` with `limit` loop through cursor and `update`.

Answer (score 0):

By default it updates only the first 1 document it found.  You need to add multi = true as an option to update() to update all. Unfortunately, update() doesn't have limit option so you can limit it to 10.

You might have to do find() with limit first and then update each document separately like mentioned in this post:

[How to limit number of updating documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590890/how-to-limit-number-of-updating-documents-in-mongodb)