# How to "(WHERE) column = column" in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I like Mongo for simple things so I was hoping to use it for something more advanced. And that worked fine until I needed this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET a = b WHERE c <> 0
```

The `a = b` part is what I can't figure out. I tried mongodb.org, but I can't find it there. I also looked for `WHERE a = b` but I can't find that either.

An alternative is so fetch all rows and than update them individually, but I don't like that. It has to be simpler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check the documentation for updating.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Your code might look like:
`db.tbl.update( { c:{$ne:0}}, { $set: { a : b } } );`

If you need to brush up on advanced queries (e.g. using `$ne`), then check here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

EDIT:
Apparently you can't update with data from the same document.
[MongoDB: Updating documents using data from the same document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document)

**EDIT 2 (solution with map reduce)**:

```
var c = new Mongo();
var db = c.getDB('db')
var s = db.getCollection('s')
s.drop();
s.save({z:1,q:5});
s.save({z:11,q:55});

db.runCommand({
mapreduce:'s',
map:function(){
  var i = this._id; //we will emit with a unique key. _id in this case
  this._id=undefined; //strange things happen with merge if you leave the id in
  //update your document with access to all fields!
  this.z=this.q;

  emit(i,this);
}, 
query:{z:1},    //apply to only certain documents
out:{merge:'s'} //results get merged (overwrite themselves in collection)
});

//now take a look
s.find();
```

Comment: The `$ne` isn't the problem. The `a = b` is. You're assigning the value `b` to the column `a`. I want to assign the value of column `b` to column `a`. Not `SET a = 'b'`, but `SET a = b`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Apparenty `update` can't refer to the current document. It can be done with map-reduce I think. Working on a solution to post...

Comment: @Rudie: Updated again with a map/reduce solution.

Comment: Whats the advantage over fetching all matching records and updating them individually? Your solution is a single transaction? (If that's even a thing in Mongo.) I really don't understand the map reduce and emit. I'll check the docs. Thanks for the example!

Comment: According to this, map & reduce are run on the server. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview