# Can MongoDB run the same operation on many documents without querying each one?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am looking for a way to update every document in a collection called "posts".

Posts get updated periodically with a popularity (sitewide popularity) and a strength (the estimated relevance to that particular user), each from different sources. What I need to do is multiply popularity and strength on each post to get a third field, relevance. Relevance is used for sorting the posts.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :popularity
  field :strength
  field :relevance
  ...
```

The current implementation is as follows:

1) I map/reduce down to a separate collection, which stores the post id and calculated relevance.

2) I update every post individually from the map reduce results.

This is a huge amount of individual update queries, and it seems silly to map each post to its own result (1-to-1), only to update the post again. Is it possible to multiply in place, or do some sort of in-place map?

Comment: This might be a duplicate if my solution here works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8230759/131227

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am hesitant to overwrite entire documents in the original collection, because the post collection is updated periodically as users take actions on the site, and I'd be worried about concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to multiply in place, or do some sort of in-place map?

Nope.

The ideal here would be to have the Map/Reduce update the Post directly when it is complete. Unfortunately, M/R does not have that capability. In theory, you could issue updates from the "finalize" stage, but this will collapse in a sharded environment.

However, if all you are doing is a simple multiplication, then you don't really need M/R at all. You can just run a big `for` loop, or you can hook up the `save` event to update `:relevance` when `:popularity` or `:strength` are updated.

MongoDB doesn't have triggers, so it can't do this automatically. But you're using a business layer which is the exact place to put this kind of logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, posts are actually user-specific, so that the same actual content may be pushed to many user feeds, but with info specific to that user (strength is user-specific). Both strength and popularity are updated using atomic updates, so a before_save won't work. While I could run a big for loop, this involves two queries (one to get and one to save) for each post, whereas with M/R I have one M/R, then one atomic update for each result.