# How do you update a field value in Mongo to equal another field's value in the same document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have some documents:

```
{"required" : 100, "total" : 30}
```

and I want to update the documents such that required = total (whatever the value of total is). I have tried:

`db.collection.update({}, {"$set" : {"required" : "total"}})`

but this sets it to the string literal "total", how do I access the value of the field, in this case `30`.

Comment: Would be great to also be able to use this in the match part of the query, and find only documents where total < required, if that is possible.

Comment: ha yeah, in query document reflection is not provided yet, outside of the aggregation framework which cannot be used to update without using it as a result set to update client side from

Comment: possible duplicate of [pymongo: updating a field using another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205060/pymongo-updating-a-field-using-another-field)

Comment: I would like to note that eval = evil in this case, I would strongly recommend not using the accepted answer on that question

Comment: What is the recommended way to do it @Sammaye ?

Comment: tbh I dunno, the only way that comes to mind atm is to pull each out and update bit by bit, that would be better than eval in this case.

Comment: @nickponline - I'd consider removing it from your data store entirely and only set the total if it's different from the `required` value. Then, you can handle the variance in a model class. (or some similar solution to that idea).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Try this instead:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(d) {
    d.required = d.total;
    db.collection.save(d);
});
```