# pymongo: Update field value based on another field value

Tags: pymongo

I wanted to update a number of records in my mongodb collection, so I wanted to duplicate the field value to another field. Here is my code:

```
res = result_collection.update_many(filter = {'requestid' : { '$in': str_req_ids }},
                                             update = {'$set': { 'original_requestid': '$requestid' }},
                                             session = session
```

I was expecting that the field `original_requestid` will be the value of the field of `requestid`, but it seems the value saved is literally `$requestid` instead. How to make sure that `$requestid` here was parsed as a value from the collection instead of a literal string?

I saw there is some approach using this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205060/pymongo-updating-a-field-using-another-field), but I prefer to use the `update_many` functionality rather than `eval` code which may cause some issues later.

Comment: If you `update_many` using an [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), it should work for you.

Comment: nevermind, I end up using `$rename` instead.