# Updating MongoDB document for geospatial searching

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Currently, I have my lat/long in separate fields in my MongoDB database, but if I want to do geospatial searching I need to have them in this format:

```
{ location : [ 50 , 30 ] }
```

By what means can I transpose the values of my lat/long keys into a new key per document as per above?

TIA!

Comment: Read out the old document, flip the values, write the result.  Don't lost track of which ones you updated.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  Just was wondering how. This post seems to cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate through all your documents that don't have a `location` field and add it (presumably deleting the lat/long fields unless this will break your application).

```
db.mycollection.find( { location : { $exists : false } } ).forEach(
    function (doc) {
        // Add (lon, lat) pairs .. order is important
        doc.location = { lon: doc.lon, lat: doc.lat };

        // Remove old properties
        delete doc.lon;
        delete doc.lat;

        // Save the updated document
        db.mycollection.save(doc);
    }
)
```

Note that the order for MongoDB [geospatial indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/) should be consistent in your document as (longitude, latitude).

Comment: Of course it's transposing...what would you call it??  I want to change the shape of the data not the actual values (i.e., transforming).  I get how to find the docs, but I'm unsure the mechanism to iterate...is that map reduce function or something?

Comment: @occasl: you're correct, transposing is an appropriate term .. I inferred something else.  Map/reduce copies into a new output collection so if you want to iterate in place a forEach is appropriate.  Revised the example to include an update.

Comment: Thanks...that's what I ended up doing.