# MongoDB: Modify each document on server

Tags: mongodb

Given a large (millions+) collection of documents similar to:

```
{ _id : ObjectId, "a" : 3, "b" : 5 }
```

What is the most efficient way to process these documents directly on the server, with the results added to each document within the same collection?  For example, add a key `c` whose value equals `a+b`.

```
{ _id : ObjectId, "a" : 3, "b" : 5, "c" : 8 }
```

I'd prefer to do this in the shell.

Seems that `find().forEach()` would waste time in transit between the db and the shell, and `mapReduce()` seems intended to process groups of objects down into aggregated data (though I may be misunderstanding).

**EDIT:** I'd prefer a solution that doesn't block, if there is one (other than using a cursor on the client)...

Comment: Seems I could do this with db.eval(): http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D, but that will be blocking.  I thought perhaps update() would work, but it doesn't seem to be possible to reference the iterated document from within an update(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document.  So, doesn't seem to be a way to do this without blocking except a forEach on a client-side cursor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MongoDB Docs on db.eval()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D):

"db.eval() is used to evaluate a function (written in JavaScript) at the database server.
This is useful if you need to touch a lot of data lightly. In that scenario, network transfer of the data could be a bottleneck."

The documentation has an example of how to use it that is very similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: right, as i wrote in my comment above it looks like db.eval() is a possibility, but it's blocking.  didn't mention i'd prefer not to block...

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is your best option. I would run it on the server (from the shell) to reduce latency.