# How to iterate and update documents with PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple, single-client setup for MongoDB and PyMongo 2.6.3. The goal is to iterate over each document in the collection `collection` and update (`save`) each document in the process. The approach I'm using looks roughly like:

```
cursor = collection.find({})
index = 0
count = cursor.count()
while index != count:
    doc = cursor[index]
    print 'updating doc ' + doc['name']
    # modify doc ..
    collection.save(doc)
    index += 1
cursor.close()
```

**The problem is that `save` is apparently modifying the order of documents in the cursor.** For example, if my collection is made of 3 documents (`id`s omitted for clarity):

```
{
    "name": "one"
}
{
    "name": "two"
}
{
    "name": "three"
}
```

the above program outputs:

```
> updating doc one
> updating doc two
> updating doc two
```

If however, the line `collection.save(doc)` is removed, the output becomes:

```
> updating doc one
> updating doc two
> updating doc three
```

Why is this happening? What is the right way to safely iterate *and* update documents in a collection?

Comment: This is not an answer. But try `1 + 999 is 1000` and ``1 + 999 == 1000`.

Comment: @falsetru thx was just recreating for simplicity, still learning python :). ok now?

Comment: how are you modifying the docs? is `doc['name'] = 'newValue'` enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer in MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/):

> Because the cursor is not isolated during its lifetime, intervening write operations on a document may result in a cursor that returns a document more than once if that document has changed. To handle this situation, see the information on [snapshot mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-isolate-cursors).

Snapshot mode is enabled on the cursor, and makes a nice guarantee:

> `snapshot()` traverses the index on the `_id` field and guarantees that the query will return each document (with respect to the value of the `_id` field) no more than once.

To enable snapshot mode with PyMongo:

```
cursor = collection.find(spec={},snapshot=True)
```

as per PyMongo `find()` [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find). Confirmed that this fixed my problem.

Comment: Looks like `snapshot` was deprecated in MongoDB 3.6 and removed in Mongo DB 4.0. Haven't found a solution without `snapshot` `find()` [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find).

Comment: Found a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12589792/828394.

Answer (score 5):

Snapshot does the work.

But on pymongo 2.9 and onwards, the syntax is slightly different.

```
cursor = collection.find(modifiers={"$snapshot": True})
```

or for any version,

```
cursor = collection.find({"$snapshot": True})
```

as per the [PyMongo documentations](http://api.mongodb.org/python/3.2/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#snapshot-and-max-scan-replaced-by-modifiers)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't recreate your situation but maybe, off the top of my head, because fetching the results like you're doing it get's them one by one from the db, you're actually creating more as you go (saving and then fetching the next one).

You can try holding the result in a list (that way, your fetching all results at once - **might be heavy**, depending on your query):

```
cursor = collection.find({})
# index = 0
results = [res for res in cursor] #count = cursor.count()
cursor.close()
for res in results: # while index != count //This will iterate the list without you needed to keep a counter:
    # doc = cursor[index] // No need for this since 'res' holds the current record in the loop cycle
    print 'updating doc ' + res['name'] # print 'updating doc ' + doc['name']
    # modify doc ..
    collection.save(res)
    # index += 1 // Again, no need for counter
```

Hope it helps