# how do I modify the value of a string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query that finds the items I'm looking for:

```
db.user.find({email:/xhjvv123/}).pretty()
```

These are emails that all have that string (`xhjvv123`) as the first 8 characters.  I want to find all emails with that string and then remove the string.

I think I can use `$substr`, but I can only find examples that return data.  How to I actually change the string?

**EDIT** based on comments

ex.  I have an email `xhjvv123dbw@test.com`.  I want to change the email to just `dbw@test.com`.  This will be true for hundreds of emails; i want to find all the emails with the string `xhjvv123`, remove that string, and leave the rest of the email intact.

Comment: Have you tried: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/  and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/    these should help you giving more insight in changing value

Comment: @akshay Thanks!  But, don't those require that the new data all be the same?  If I was replacing every email I found with the same string, I could use those.  I'm just trying to remove the same part of each string, but the string left behind is different every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document

Comment: Do you want to update your documents?

Comment: @Michael Hopefully my edits have cleared up exactly what I'm trying to do.  I don't want to use the `update` function in particular.  I want to use whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

If your email stars with exact matching `xhjvv123` this then use following query to remove :

```
db.collectionName.remove({"email":{"$regex":"^\\xhjvv123"}})
```

Or if email contains `xhjvv123` this in any where then use above as

```
db.collectionName.remove({"email":{"$regex":"\\xhjvv123"}})
```

more about [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

**EDIT**

If you want to update matching email to other then use same in `query` and use your email in `set` as below :

```
db.collectionName.update({"email":{"$regex":"^\\xhjvv123"}},{"$set":{"email":"dbw@test.com"}},false,true)
```

or

```
db.collectionName.update({"email":{"$regex":"\\xhjvv123"}},{"$set":{"email":"dbw@test.com"}},false,true)
```

Or simply try this :

```
db.collectionName.update({"email":{"$regex":"xhjvv123"}},{"$set":{"email":"dbw@test.com"}},false,true)
```

Other option

If you run this on mongo shell

```
var regex = /xhjvv123/
var matchingEmail = "xhjvv123dbw@test.com"
var result = matchingEmail.replace(regex,"")
db.collectionName.update({"email":regex},{"$set":{"email":result}},false,true)
```

[update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

> multi is set to true, the update() method updates all documents that meet the  criteria.

So I don't think to iterate over all documents and replace string, **multi:true** do the job :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to remove the entire email.  I just want to remove the part that I'm using to identify the email.  So i'm trying to remove the part of the email that has the string.   ex. I have an email `xhjvv123dbw@test.com`.  I want to change the email to just `dbw@test.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`cursor.forEach`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method with the [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

```js
var reg = /xhjvv123/;
db.user.find({ email: reg }).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.email = doc.email.replace(reg, "");
    db.user.save(doc);
})
```

---

Demo

```js
> db.user.insert({'email': "xhjvv123dbw@test.com"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> var reg = /xhjvv123/;
> db.user.find({ email: reg }).forEach(function(doc){
...     doc.email = doc.email.replace(reg, "");
...     db.user.save(doc);
... })
> db.user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556f76e82db797abad412f56"), "email" : "dbw@test.com" }
>
```

Comment: I tried this using the mongo shell  and could not get it to work.  i'm sure, however, that i'm doing something wrong.  Do I need to put it in a script?

Comment: @dwstein what do you mean by *could not get to work*? added demo

Answer (score 0):

please try below :

```
db.user.find({"email":/xhjvv123/}).ForEach( function(mydoc)
{
mydoc.email = mydoc.email.slice(9,this.email.length);
db.user.save(mydoc);
}
);
```

(or)

```
May be we you can try below as well in shell, not sure though :

db.user.update( {"email":/xhjvv123/}, {$set:{"email":{this.email.slice(9,this.email.length)}} , multi:true};
```