# MongoDB Replace string between some Specific String

Tags: mongodb, grunt-string-replace

I don't know how to replace string between some Specific String Query in MongoDb

eg. 
**"SearchDisplayTag" : "Ceramic Wall Tile Somany Agata Brown Glossy 6",**

i want to replace specific string "**Ceramic Wall Tile**" to "**Somany Tile**"
can any one help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document ?

Comment: @golddragon007 Tanks, but i already try this query.. it doesn't work , and someone is replace whole string.. not string between.. i need replace string between exact string