# How to apply a regex to a MongoDB field

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have an aggregation query. In the `$addToFields` stage of the query I need to add another field that is a regex of another field. For example, here is an example document:

```
{
     "host": "axcc91-calpw-11299",
     "site": "gate9",
     "type": "router"
}
```

I need to apply this regex: `^([^-\d]+)` which will produce axcc from the above document. Here is the document i need produced:

```
{
     "host": "axcc91-calpw-11299",
     "site": "gate9",
     "type": "router",
     "host2": "axcc"
}
```

How would I apply a regex to either a $project or $addToFields stage to produce the host2 field?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262746/171318

Comment: For aggregation there is still an open ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947