# Mongoose find and replace specific phrase the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, text-search

I have documents like this:

```
    {
      _id: 'some id',
      body: 'i want some apple',
    },

    {
      _id: 'some id2',
      body: 'i want some apple and banana',
    }
```

And i want to find and replace all of document's body phrase `some apple`  to `lots of oranges`.

Expected Results:

```
    {
      _id: 'some id',
      body: 'i want lots of oranges',
    },

    {
      _id: 'some id2',
      body: 'i want lots of oranges and banana',
    }
```

So i find all the documents with this:

```
    myDB.find({
        "body": {
          "$regex": "some apple",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      },
      function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
      }
    );
)
```

But don't know how to replace and update only document's specific body phrase `some apple`  to `lots of oranges`.

How do i do this?

Comment: If you are using `mongodb 4.2` version which allows `aggregation pipeline` in update. [This does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556298/6082280)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace substring in mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider mongoDB [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-index)

You can implement by creating and index likee this:

```
db.yourCollectionName.createIndex({ body: "text" });
```

After which you can run this query:

```
db.yourCollectionName.updateMany(
      { $text: { $search: "\"some apple\"" }},
      { $set: { body: "i want lots of oranges" }},
      { new: true }
);
```

That should do it

Comment: I created index body use ```myDB.index({body: 'text'}) ``` but how could i apply with mongoose that query?

Comment: The same query should work with your mongoose model @yong

Answer (score 2):

you can loop through and update

```
db.people.find({
    body: {
        $regex: "some apple",
        $options: "i"
    }
}).forEach(doc => {
    doc.body = doc.body.replace(/some apple/ig, 'lots of oranges');
    db.people.update({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { body: doc.body } });
});
```