# Mongo - Replace substring of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, mongoose

Im having trouble replacing a substring in some documents.
This would be the example of one of the many similar documents:

```
{
"images" : [
    {
        "url" : "https://example/1234"
    },
    {
        "url" : "https://example/afaef"
    },
    {
        "url" : "https://example/abcdef"
    }
]}
```

I need to replace all the '**example**' substrings for say '**newresult**'

This is my approach

```
db.collection.find({'images.url':/.*example*/} , {'images.url':true, _id:false}).forEach(function(doc) {
doc.images.url = doc.images.url.replace('example', 'newresult');
db.collection.save(doc);});
```

However im getting many errors trying different forms of this like
doc.images.url is undefined. Also tried some different yet still unsuccesful variations of this.

I would really appreciate some insights on what im doing wrong, or if theres a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: mongo version is 4.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace substring in mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document)

Comment: Nope, its the same that i tried myself

Comment: You can try answer from 'Xavier Guihot' on the same link, it should work for your case..

Comment: Since the doc that you pass to `save` does not have an `_id` it will create a new document in the collection.  Was that the intent?

Comment: The intent is to find all replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some MongoDB solution but if it's one-off JS script then you're close, the only thing you're missing is that `images` is an array so you need to use `.map()` like below:

```js
let doc = {
"images" : [
    {
        "url" : "https://example/1234"
    },
    {
        "url" : "https://example/afaef"
    },
    {
        "url" : "https://example/abcdef"
    }
]};

doc.images= doc.images.map(({url, ...rest}) => ({url: url.replace('example', 'newresult'), ...rest}));

console.log(doc);
```

Comment: Mmm, isnt working. I think it could be because my doc is in the format of {"images":[...]} as opposed to "images":[...]   ?

Comment: can you `console.log(doc)` and paste it here?

Comment: It might also be that you're not retrieving `_id` so if you want to update current docs then you have to get rid of `_id: false`

Comment: [object BSON] is the output

Comment: try `printjson(doc)`

Comment: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("eafafa343"),
 "images" : [
  {
   "url" : "example/..."
  },
  {
   "url" : "example/.."
  },
  {
   "url" : "example/aefeaf"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: This looks valid, please also remove `'images.url':true` and check my modified answer if you have more fields in `images` and try again