# Convert string to int in aggregate in mongoDB using nodejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Data stored in mongoDB::**

*TotalStudent,TotalPresent all are in string.*

```
[{'_id':'12sdsd','TotalStudent:'1,233,273','TotalPresent':'23'},
{'_id':'22fdf','TotalStudent:'2,445,232','TotalPresent':'32'}]
```

**Node js::** I tried to Aggregate and give me the output of the total number of students and total number of present.

P.S.: I have used mongoose to fetch data from mongoDB.

```
covid_data.aggregate([{
        $group:{
            _id:"",
            TotalStudents:{$sum:{$toInt:"$TotalStudents"}},
            TotalPresent:{$sum:{$toInt:"$TotalPresent"}}
        }
    }], (err,docs)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(docs);
            res.send(docs);
        }
    });
```

**It gives me error as::**

"Failed to parse number '1,233,273' in $convert with no onError value: Bad digit \",\" while parsing 1,233,273"."codeName":"ConversionFailure"

**Edit1**

Edited sample data's TotalStudents number format. As it also contains **,**.
Previously I failed to include the TotalStudents contains number as "1,233,273" and "2,445,232".Because of which while trying to convert I'm getting the error.

Any help will be really appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: Data types are important, use numbers instead of string when you create your collections, at least in your db instance. If your data comes in that way you can always handle it in a different way when you import it. If you don't do that you will ended up having an Armageddon of workarounds instead of a query.

Comment: Thing is I scrapped the data from a website and got the data from overthere. And stored the data in mongoDb. Because of which I didn't have control on what type it saves the data

Comment: I understand you very well, but your data has to be sanified if you want reliable results. If what you do is a "one shot" operation, you can risk and skip it but... If your data is incremental, a layer that fix consistency might be needed.

Comment: @Ajax if you scrapped the data, that means you are the one who can control how the data enters the database. Otherwise you might want to iterate through the data and update it to an appropriate format at the application layer.

Comment: @Ajax : So the concept everyone is talking about is : *write it once in a perfect way to read it n times with ease*.. So now we need to do n num of tricks to make it work each time we read it, So do you wanna update all data with numbers ? - I would say to do it or even I can provide a query which will work but I would not opt it over updating data to correct format..

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.....I will update my data to apprpriate format which be best practice. I will accept the answer of @whoami as it works for the properly formated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting MongoDB version >= `4.0` you can use [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) to convert string to int, Try below code :

```
covid_data.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "",
        TotalStudents: { $sum: { $toInt: "$TotalStudent" } },
        TotalPresent: { $sum: { $toInt: "$TotalPresent" } }
      }
    }
  ], (err,docs)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    }
});
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IG914D-2Q9Q)

**Note :** In your `$group` stage, `_id` has to be `_id: ""` in order to group on all documents(Using `_id:"$_id"` will result in returning almost same data as is as `_id` is unique for each doc). Plus you've couple of typos at `$sum`, at 
`{$sum:"TotalPresent"}` also at `{$Sum:"$TotalStudents"}`.

**Update :** Updated answer with new requirement : As original query is failing due to having `,` :  `'1,233,273'`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** Re-create two string fields without `,` */
  {
    $addFields: { 
    TotalStudent: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $split: [ "$TotalStudent", "," ] },
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }
        }
      },
    TotalPresent: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $split: [ "$TotalPresent", "," ] },
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      TotalStudents: { $sum: { $toInt: "$TotalStudent" } },
      TotalPresent: { $sum: { $toInt: "$TotalPresent" } }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kRWHuRLHX06)

We need to split string based on delimiter `,` & concat all the strings in array to one string using `$reduce`. This can be avoided by use of `$replaceOne` starting MongoDB version >= `4.4`, Check this :: [how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document) , Use this link in case if you wanted to update data.

**Note :** I would highly suggest to consider my above comment :

> So the concept everyone is talking about is : write it once in a
>   perfect way to read it n times with ease.. So now we need to do n num
>   of tricks to make it work each time we read it, So do you wanna update
>   all data with numbers ? - I would say to do it or even I can provide a
>   query which will work but I would not opt it over updating data to
>   correct format.

Comment: I've edited my question as my number which in this case is a string also contains "," which i failed to include because of which it's not able to convert. Can you please have a look and suggest me.