# How to bulk replace substring in mongoDB array field with keyword?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f08e58ae1f788a8beb30519"),
    "__v": NumberInt("0"),
    "dimensions": {
        "height": NumberInt("720"),
        "width": NumberInt("1080")
    },
    "likes": NumberInt("164"),
    "src": [
        "http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfUrBufC7T3R48ehjSrVSQ7JbfkgFybzjLs4tNMXhX7YmuWicPe2NUiaKQ/0",
        "http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfkopmyeak2h1oGPkiaHcgcg4DX5swbBHRg6TWibl2ocvpgIaAng0koWMQ/0",
        "http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfkxTnwtOurQQkajmtlQzIokIM0Ms6qyYh2FCWaCnZqmxOAyEYZyUgdA/0",
        "http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFflamticYWfNkheTMtzcz3wSGib01EsurUA3Royy1A1P0W8muEicMcbbegw/0",
        "http://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfRc3IBJE1amD5BPoELdYjoIvkQ2iaHiaUu0HexWD8niaAJq6fTFIqDgibOA/0"
    ],
    "recommended": true
}
```

Let's say I have above data structure in mongoDB in a collection "discoveries" and I want to replace `http://` in src to `https://` like such:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f08e58ae1f788a8beb30519"),
    "__v": NumberInt("0"),
    "dimensions": {
        "height": NumberInt("720"),
        "width": NumberInt("1080")
    },
    "likes": NumberInt("164"),
    "src": [
        "https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfUrBufC7T3R48ehjSrVSQ7JbfkgFybzjLs4tNMXhX7YmuWicPe2NUiaKQ/0",
        "https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfkopmyeak2h1oGPkiaHcgcg4DX5swbBHRg6TWibl2ocvpgIaAng0koWMQ/0",
        "https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfkxTnwtOurQQkajmtlQzIokIM0Ms6qyYh2FCWaCnZqmxOAyEYZyUgdA/0",
        "https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFflamticYWfNkheTMtzcz3wSGib01EsurUA3Royy1A1P0W8muEicMcbbegw/0",
        "https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz_jpg/VZYVS8SibfiaibUE9qr4M2nGG50icSCuiaGFfRc3IBJE1amD5BPoELdYjoIvkQ2iaHiaUu0HexWD8niaAJq6fTFIqDgibOA/0"
    ],
    "recommended": true
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this without going through each record and then update them one by one? (I have millions of records it would take massive among of time, also it would seem inefficient...)

I tried:

```
db.getCollection("discoveries").updateMany(
  { src: { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: { src: {
      $replaceOne: { input: "src.$[]", find: "http://", replacement: "https://" }
    }}
  }]
)
```

It returns:

```
[Error] Error: collection.updateOne requires update operator
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556298/8296184

Comment: @VirgilioGM there is a little bit of problem with this solution, src is an array rather than a string, so $replaceOne doesn't seem to do it...

Comment: I don't have my computer to try it now, sorry, but I thought it would work using 'src.$[]' as the field to be updated

Comment: @VirgilioGM thx, see my updated question. it returns: `collection.updateOne requires update operator`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more of (ask specific than generic IMO) takes an assumption that all strings in `src` originally starts with `http` and are needed to replaced with `https`.

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for
> update operations.

**Idea:** Is to use an aggregation pipe using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) where all urls in `src` splitted at 4th index forward joined with **https** using [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) and [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/). And update `src` property using `$set`.

```
db.collection.updateMany({ src: { $exists: true } }, [
  {
    $set: {
      src: {
        $map: {
          input: "$src",
          as: "u",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "https",
              {
                $substr: ["$$u", 4, -1],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

**NOTE:** [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) can also be used to tweak this, instead of [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/).

---

**EDIT/UPDATE:** Based on comments that some urls could already be starting with `https`.

```
db.collection.updateMany({ src: { $exists: true } }, [
  {
    $set: {
      src: {
        $map: {
          input: "$src",
          as: "u",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $split: ["$$u", "http:"],
                    },
                  },
                  2,
                ],
              },
              then: {
                $concat: [
                  "https:",
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      {
                        $split: ["$$u", "http:"],
                      },
                      1,
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
              else: "$$u",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: `an assumption that all strings in src originally starts with http and are needed to replaced with https`... that's not exactly how it is in reality

Comment: @AeroWang Ermm.. made this query purely based on the example in the question. So u'r saying some urls in `src` may already be starting with `https`?

Comment: u'r saying some urls in src may already be starting with https - yes

Comment: @AeroWang Updated the response! the solution turned out be less than optimal but works. I don't have mongo 4.4 to test out `$replaceOne` which could greatly work here. Hope someone posts a better solution. You might wanna look at [Another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466982/6082280) which I would have gone for in case of huge data.