# How can I replace a substring with another in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want to replace a substring "are" with "any test" in all "ques" document of "user" collection,but my query is replace the full document string with "any test".I am new to mongo.
Please someone suggest me what wrong with my query?

Here is my mongo query.

```
db.user.find({ques:{$regex:'are'}}).forEach(function (e, i) {e.ques =  e.ques.replace(/are/, 'any test'), printjson(e); db.ques.save(e);} )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace substring in mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document)

Comment: PZBird.this command
db.faq.find().forEach(function(o) {o.ques = o.ques.replace(/hello/, "How"); printjson(o);db.faq.save(o)})
is okay in localhost but in server it show that "db.faq.save" is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
db.user.find({ ques: { $regex: 'are' } }).toArray((err, users) => {
    if (err) return;
    for (const u of users) {
        u.ques = u.ques.replace(/are/, 'any test');
        db.user.save(u);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hii @lpizzinidev  I found  "MongoServerError: Expected field projectionto be of type object" error

Comment: @RatnambarGupta Try with `toArray` (see edited answer)