# How to do a self-referring UPDATE in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

For database migrations I always found it helpful to issue something like this in SQL:

`UPDATE users SET full_name = users.first_name || " " || users.last_name` (PL/SQL)
or
`UPDATE users SET full_name = CONCAT( users.first_name, users.last_name )` (MySQL)

How do I do this in MongoDB without fetching all documents first and update them by iteration?

Comment: So what **obviously doesn't work** but looks like the syntax I need is this:

`col.update({type:'user'}, {$set: {'full_name': this.first_name + " " + this.last_name} }, true, false);`

Comment: also see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958

Comment: yep. That's definitely duplicate. Didn't find those questions, though :( Thanks for pointing