# Update dependent Date field in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have documents like this in Mongoose (MongoDb):

```
{
  begin: Date,
  end: Date
}
```

All I'd like to do is to:

1. Select all documents with `end == null`
2. and then update them using `end =` "begin increased by 10 days"

How can it be done within just a single update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you cannot reference a document's current properties in an `update()`. Instead, you'll have to iterate through the documents [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958). In your case, it will look more like this:

```
db.docs.find({end:null}).forEach(
  function(doc) {
    doc.end = doc.begin + 10;
    db.docs.save(doc);
  }
)
```

This is the syntax for the Mongo shell-- you might have to make some changes for Mongoose, [as per the API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

Answer (score 1):

This query selects all documents with end = null and update it with the new date 
    `Collection.update({end:null}, {$set: {end:'new_date'}},{ multi: true });`

Comment: `new_date` must be per document dependent, i.e. it's generally different in each updated document