# How to update all documents in a collection with same key but different values?

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, documents

I have 10 documents in a collection:

```
>> {'_id':0, 'self':{....}} {'_id':1,'self':{....}} ........ {'_id':9,'self':{....}}
```

now I want to update all documents with their count, which means after the updating, the documents will look like:

```
>> {'_id':0, 'count':0, 'self':{....}} {'_id':1,'count':1, 'self':{....}} ........ {'_id':9,'count':9,'self':{....}}
```

I know there is a `update({},{'$set':{}})` method but I don't know how to use this to update different values for each document. Does anyone know some fast methods to do this?

Comment: What's count supposed to be? Might well be that you should rather use an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: You should provide enough details about what you are asking. Here is confusion in `count`? is it same as that of `_id` field?

Comment: perhaps, are you talking about `index` instead of `count`?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, count is not _id, _id is a long string with letters and numbers, count is just the No. of the documents in the collection, so if I have 100 documents, then count from 0 to 99

Comment: @Heisenberg ah yes I think you are right

Comment: Documents are unordered in collection. so you cannot do that unless it doesn't matter what the `count` value for particular document is.

Comment: @Michael, thanks a lot for your comment! That's important to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index,each in enumerate(myCollection.find({})):
    each["count"] = index
    id = each["_id"]
    each.pop("_id", None)
    collection.update({"_id":id},{"$set":each},upsert=True)
```

Note : documents are un-ordered in a collection as mentioned by @Michael

Comment: Ah, thanks for your answer, so if the index value is important for each document (i.e., it makes sense if the documents are in order), then it's useless for  me to assign the index value, right?

Comment: @gladys0313 yes it is

Comment: @Heisenberg cool! Just want to ask more: I can use sort() to sort my documents and then the index will make sense, right

Comment: @gladys0313 what is your goal?

Comment: @gladys0313: what is the significance of `count` in your application ?

Comment: @Michael, each document in my collection represents a city grid and the whole collection is a whole city. I generate the documents from left bottom to top right of the city and I want the index to follow this order

Comment: @Heisenberg, each document in my collection represents a city grid and the whole collection is a whole city. I generate the documents from left bottom to top right of the city and I want the index to follow this order

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this data structure in database:

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("4f9808648859c65d"),

"array" : [

{"text" : "foo", "value" : 11},

{"text" : "foo", "value" : 22},

{"text" : "foobar", "value" : 33}

]

}
```

You can update specific value using following query:

```
db.foo.update({"array._id" : 1}, {"$set" : {"array.$.text" : "blah"}})
```

I hope this will be helpful for you. Let me know.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, so you mean I need a for-loop to update all my documents, right

Comment: I am wondering whether for-loop is efficient, do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's fast enough but you can write a script to do that and execute with eval.

Example:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database
db.eval("var count = 0; db.collection_name.find().forEach(function(obj) { obj.count = count; db.collection_name.save(obj); count++ })")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but I got error: exception: ReferenceError: db_new is not defined near '_new.testcount.find().forEach(function(ob'

Comment: I tested again and edited the answer to be more complete. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on mongodb shell

```
> db.docs.find().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.docs.update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    count: elem._id
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Reference

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field


    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958