# Replace a word from a string

Tags: mongodb, replace, mongodb-query

I have mongodb documents with a field like this:

```
Image : http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-zoom.jpg
```

How can I replace the `zoom` part in the string value with some other text in order to get:

```
Image : http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-product2.jpg
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use mongo's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) cursor method to do an atomic update with the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set) operator  :

```
db.collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    var updated_url = doc.Image.replace('zoom', 'product2');
    db.collection.update(
        {"_id": doc._id}, 
        { "$set": { "Image": updated_url } }
    );
});
```

---

Given a very large collection to update, you could speed up things a little bit with **[`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** and restructure your update operations to be sent in bulk as:

```
var ops = [];
db.collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "Image": doc.Image.replace('zoom', 'product2') } }
        }
    });

    if ( ops.length === 500 ) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 )  
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection.update({image: 'http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-zoom.jpg'}, {$set: {image : 'http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-product2.jpg'}})
```

If you need to do this multiple times to multiple documents, you need to iterate them with a function. See here: [MongoDB: Updating documents using data from the same document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958)

Comment: there are more than 70000 enteries ur solution wont be possible

Comment: It's enough that you wouldn't want to do them by hand as my answer suggests. But the question does not specify how many documents need to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays,

- starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) (alias of `db.collection.update`) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value.
- starting `Mongo 4.4`, the new aggregation operator [`$replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne) makes it very easy to replace part of a string.

```js
// { "Image" : "http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-zoom.jpg" }
// { "Image" : "http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-boom.jpg" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "Image": { $regex: /zoom/ } },
  [{
    $set: { "Image": {
      $replaceOne: { input: "$Image", find: "zoom", replacement: "product2" }
    }}
  }]
)
// { "Image" : "http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-product2.jpg" }
// { "Image" : "http://static14.com/p/Inc.5-Black-Sandals-5131-2713231-7-boom.jpg" }
```

- The first part (`{ "Image": { $regex: /zoom/ } }`) is just there to make the query faster by filtering which documents to update (the ones containing `"zoom"`)
- The second part (`$set: { "Image": {...`) is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline):

  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator (`Mongo 4.2`) which in this case replaces the value of a field.
  - The new value is computed with the new [`$replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne) operator. Note how `Image` is modified directly based on the its own value (`$Image`).