# change collection data formats within Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Looking for the best way to fix data formats in my Meteor app. When I started, I wasn't using anything like SimpleSchema **or** being as consistent as I should have been with Date formats.

So now I'd like to get everything back to proper Date objects.

I'm still new-ish to Mongo, and I was a little surprised to find- and please correct me if I'm wrong- that there's no way to update all records and modify an attribute using its current value. I've got timestamps that came from an API POST that might be `String`s, epoch times from `new Date().getTime()`, some actual `Date`s, etc.

I plan to use moment(currentValue).toDate() to fix this. I'm using [percolate:migrations](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations) for data changes 1) so that changes stay in my repo and 2) so data is consistent wherever the app is run. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958) and I assume I'll need to iterate over my collections. But `snapshot()` isn't available in Meteor.

Do I need to write and manually run a mongo script for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I prefer to run migration scripts from the mongo shell since it's easier to execute (compared to deploying the code that runs the migration) and it gives you access to the full mongo api. You can run `load(path/to/script)` in the mongo console if you want to pre define your script.

`snapshot()` ensures you wont modify the same document twice. From [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/)

> Append the snapshot() method to a cursor to toggle the “snapshot” mode. This ensures that the query will not return a document multiple times, even if intervening write operations result in a move of the document due to the growth in document size.

Running without `snapshot()` would possibly result in passing a date object (that was just converted) to your update function. Since you are planning to cover this case already (you are saying you already have some date objects in your db) it doesnt change much. Ergo, you can run this from meteor without `snapshot()` but you might as well use the shell to get used to it :)

And you are correct that there is no way to update a document based on its current value. Looping through all documents and updating them one by one is rather slow, so if you have a huge collection you might want to schedule some downtime.

Comment: Thanks @datacarl.  Crazy that I actually have to update each one. :)