# Mongo db : query on nested json

Tags: mongodb, find

Sample json object :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "55887982498e2bef5a5f96db" ),
  "a" : "x",
  "q" : "null",
  "p" : "",
  "s" : "{\"f\":{\"b\":[\"I\"]},\"time\":\"fs\"}" }
```

need all documents where time = fs
My query :

```
{"s":{"time" : "fs"}}
```

above returns zero products but that is not true.

Comment: As far as I can "s" contains a simple string so there is no way it query like this will work.

Comment: So is it not possible to query on such documents

Comment: You can always use [`regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) but it will be rather slow. Is there any particular reason why you keep field as a string and not a nested document?

Comment: Nested document would have allowed being query upon ?, any how-to about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. First of all `s` is clearly a string so your query cannot work. You can use `$regex` as below but it won't be very efficient:

```
{s: {$regex: '"time"\:"fs"'}}
```

I would suggest converting `s` fields to proper documents. You can use `JSON.parse` to do it. Documents can be updated based on a current value using `db.foo.find().snapshot().forEach`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/1560062) for details.

Second problem is your query is simply wrong. To match `time` field you should use dot notation:

```
{"s.time" : "fs"})
```