# Conditional updates in mongo

Tags: mongodb

When working on MySQL, I can setup an UPDATE based on the current value of the field as such:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1;
```

Or

```
UPDATE table SET field = IF(field == 1, 0, 1);
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can do something similar in Mongo. If I want to do something like an if or trinary operator, can I do that in Mongo?

Comment: See $inc to increment - Here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$inc` for incremental updates

```
db.update({}, {$inc: { field: 1 }}, {multi: true});
```

For a ternary operator in your example you can use `$bit`, however it is a hurdle to access data from document during update

```
db.update({}, {$bit: { field: {xor: 1} }}, {multi: true});
```

Comment: Interesting. I knew about increment, so that was a poor example for me to make; I was more curious about how to alter fields based on their existing values. I see that's harder to do than expected.

Comment: You will have to iterate on each document.Mongo does allow to do that server side.

Comment: a generic solution would be smth like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/5051250