# MongoDB - Update only time to datetime

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find a way to update only the "time" part. (only with mongodb)

For example, I have the following datetimes

```
2018-01-03 01:00:00.000
2018-01-04 02:00:00.000
2018-01-05 03:00:00.000
```

And I want to update only the time. The desired result is

```
2018-01-03 10:00:00.000
2018-01-04 10:00:00.000
2018-01-05 10:00:00.000
```

Comment: is this question ? what is your data , time come from where?

Comment: Will the query be used in the mongo shell, or a driver? In the last case which one?

Comment: I'm using mongo with nodejs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760736/how-to-update-collection-and-increment-hours-for-iso-date

Comment: You will need to load and update each document. The above link points to a good example showing the basic approach.

Comment: This link might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262746/9297144