# mongodb Replace a portion of a string

Tags: mongodb

I have a field

```
"data" : {
        "user" : "derp",
        "id" : "xHOSTNAME_xderp"
```

I want to replace all docs with xHOSTNAME_* to yHOSTNAME_.
Any idea how to search and replace. I've seen some other posts similarly related but none seemed to work.

Comment: Wrong link: Same basic question but answers are more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958

Answer (score 8):

```js
db.test1.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.data.id = doc.data.id.replace('xHOSTNAME_', 'yHOSTNAME_');
    db.test1.save(doc);
});
```