# Add time to $currentDate in $set statement

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to perform 2 operations in one `findOneAndUpdate()`:

- Update date in one field `lastUpdatedTimestamp`, set it to current date (this one works fine in my statement),
- Update date in other field `expiryTimestamp`, by adding 1 day to `$currentDate` (I couldn't find a way to achieve it so I'm trying to `$add` 1 day to the the value read from the above field `lastUpdatedTimestamp`) - (I can't make this one work).

  ```
  findOneAndUpdate(
      {"_id":123}, 
      { $currentDate: {"lastUpdatedTimestamp":true}, $set: {"expiryTimestamp": {$add: ["$lastUpdatedTimestamp", 24*60*60000]}}}
  )
  ```

Here's the error I'm receiving:
`{ "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$add' in 'expiryTimestamp.$add' is not valid for storage.", "code" : 52 }`

Is it even possible? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3100115 thanks for your suggestion. My exact problem lies in the `$add` expression. Is it permitted in that context, or only in `aggregate()`?

Comment: You can only use `$add` with `aggregate()`.  Also do you want to use the `$currentDate` to set "expiryTimestamp"?

Comment: I want to use `$currentdate + 1 day` for `expiryTimestamp`

Comment: So why are you using "lastUpdatedTimestamp" to set "expiryTimestamp"?

Comment: I have amended the question. What I'm trying to achieve is to add time to `$currentdate`. Something like `dateAdd(day, 1, getDate())` in SQL. Is it possible?

Comment: To update one field using another field in the same document, you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958)

Comment: @gzc the answer you linked has nothing to do with this question

Comment: @user3100115 OP want to update `expiryTimestamp` by adding 1 day to new `lastUpdatedTimestamp`.

Comment: @gzc note that what OP really wants to do is update "expiryTimestamp" to  `$currentDate + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) method to set the "expiryTimestamp" value.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "_id": 123 },  
    { "$set": { 
        "lastUpdatedTimestamp": new Date(),  
        "expiryTimestamp": new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) 
    }}
)
```

You don't need to use [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) unless you want to return the new or old document.

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer is wrong in the sense that using `new Date()` will not use database timestamp which is important if your server and database hosted on different region and also count network time for sending data. To correctly do this, use `$currentDate` like this:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 123 }, {
   $set: { /** update doc here **/ },
   $currentDate: { lastUpdatedTimestamp: true} 
});
```

Similarly using `updateOne`

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: 123 }, {
   $set: { /** update doc here **/ },
   $currentDate: { lastUpdatedTimestamp: true} 
});
```