# Mongodb regex - how to find a substring that contains '..' at the end or '.' in the middle of a mongo field?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I need to scan a few thousand documents in Mongo and find records for which a field has the following substrings:

1. any text followed by 2 dots. For example: Co..
2. any text that contains a '.' in the middle (i.e. not first and not last) of a string

Also, for either case is there a way to automatically remove the extraneous '.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regular expression you're looking for:

`/(.+\..+)|(\.\.$)/`

You can check [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hF2wJ8/1) for thorough explaination.

> Also, for either case is there a way to automatically remove the extraneous '.'?

You'll need to iterate through found documents, alter them manually and later save. For a more thorough explaination please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958)