# MongoDB Update Document using existing value

Tags: mongodb

How can an existing document be updated using it's own values?

A collection of Album exists which contains photos, the photo webpath needs modifying to prepend the existing value.

The following is based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/1283381

The code below fails to update the webPath value.

```
db.getCollection('Album').find().snapshot().forEach(
      function (e) {
        for(var i=0; i<e.photos.length; i++) {
            e.photos[i].webPath = '/uploads'+e.photos[i].webPath;
        }
            db.events.save(e);
    }
)
```

Output is:

```
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 2ms
```

**Edit 1**

Sample Album document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5923e3eebe37843815248521"),
    "created" : ISODate("2017-05-23T07:25:34.000Z"),
    "photos" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 474,
        "webPath" : "/dir/to.jpg"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 475,
        "webPath" : "/dir/to.jpg"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post a sample document of your collection for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving to the wrong collection.

After you loop over your photos and update the data, you have this line:

```
db.events.save(e);
```

I expect you were intending to save back to the original collection you queried from. However this is saving to the `events` collection (and creating it if it doesn't exist) because both of the following lines are equivalent ([see MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/)). You'll likely find you've got an events collection full of your modified data.

```
db.foo.save(x);
db.getCollection('foo').save();
```

Instead, you'll want to make sure you're saving back to the original collection you're querying (the `Album` collection). In your case, this can simply be a change to:

```
db.getCollection('Album').save(e);
```

Your full snippet would look like this:

```
db.getCollection('Album').find().snapshot().forEach(
      function (e) {
        for(var i=0; i<e.photos.length; i++) {
            e.photos[i].webPath = '/uploads'+e.photos[i].webPath;
        }
        db.getCollection('Album').save(e);
    }
)
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake, thank you.  You are right I just found an events collection with lots of data.

Comment: Great to hear - we've all been there :-). I'm glad I could help you out.