# MongoDB Finding nested object value

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find documents within my collection that have a numeric value greater than x amount. The documentation explains how to do this for top level values however I'm struggling to retrieve the correct data for values that are within child objects.

Sample JSON

`{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c32646c9f3315c3e8300673"),
 "key" : "20190107",
        "__v" : 0,
        "chart" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c3372e5c35e924984f28e03"),
                        "volume" : "0",
                        "close" : "47.24",
                        "time" : "09:30 AM"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c3372e5c35e924984f28d34"),
                        "volume" : "50",
                        "close" : "44.24",
                        "time" : "09:50 AM"
                }
        ]
}`

I want to retrieve volumes greater than 10. I've tried

`db.symbols.find({"chart.volume": { $gt: 10 } } )`

`db.symbols.find({"volume": { $gt: 10 } } )`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample JSON has string values for the `chart.volume` field. If it was numeric, then your first solution:

> db.symbols.find({"chart.volume": { $gt: 10 } } )

would work fine. The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) do explain how to do this.

Comment: Ahhh of course! Thank you. I don't suppose there is a way I can easily recursively change all of the values to numbers without having to rescrape/import them?

Comment: There is. You can do this `db.symbols.find().forEach(
  function (e) {
    e.chart = e.chart.map(c => {
  c.volume = parseInt(c.volume);
  return c;
 });

    db.symbols.save(e);
  }
)`. Refer to these answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792958/5800527) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41853085/5800527)