# How to push a field's value into another array field of same doc in MongoDB update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one mongodb object like below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e54934b2dfddc1826223bbb"),
    "sellProducts" : {
        "products" : []
    },
    "sellServices" : {
        "services" : []
    },
    "categories" : [],
    "status" : "Published",
    "tags" : [],
    "dateRange" : [],
    "membershipRequired" : false,
    "usersAttending" : [],
    "cities" : [],
    "companies" : [ 
        ObjectId("5db1c84ec10c45224c4b95fd"),
    ],
    "companyId" : ObjectId("5db1c84ec10c45224c4b95fd"),
    "jobProfile" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e549339a3ad20c97b7b0c7d")
    ],
    "fundingBy" : []
}
```

Now I want to update the same record by pushing the value of the **companyId** field into the array of **companies**. How can I do that?

I tried below query but It didn't work :

```
db.getCollection('posts').update({_id: ObjectId("5e54934b2dfddc1826223bbb")},
    {
        $push: 
            {
                companies: "$$companyId"
            }
    })
```

Comment: what is your db version ?

Comment: structure of $$company?

Comment: @whoami, DB version is 4.2.0

Comment: @mehta-rohan, I update the question. It's companyId not a company.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: @whoami, No this question is a little bit different. They concat two strings, I want to push the value to an array.

Comment: @JaySojitra : If you get the concept it would be easy !! It's not about concatenation of two strings or pushing value that question about using existing field value in document while updates - So which is exactly same !! Please read and try it if not let us know...

Comment: @whoami, I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788256/mongodb-updating-documents-using-data-from-the-same-document/3792958#3792958), but somehow It won't work.

Comment: Also @whoami, I am trying to update this from robo3t console itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using MongoDB version `4.2` where you can actually run aggregation pipeline in updates, Try below query :

```
/** As `$push` doesn't work in aggregation as update operator
 * You can use `$addFields` or `$set` to re-create 'companies' field by merging 'companies' array with array converted 'companyId' field
 * which would leave 'companies' as an array with existing elements + companyId */

db.getCollection('posts').updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5e54934b2dfddc1826223bbb")},
         [{$addFields : {companies: {$concatArrays: ['$companies',['$companyId']]}}}])
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. But when I execute your script it gives me below error:

"Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:"

Comment: @JaySojitra : In the past I’ve observed robo3T has issues using aggregation pipeline in updates especially with updateMany() & updateOne(), just try with update() !!