# Swapping two fields around in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have accidentally inserted the email and name columns around the wrong way

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("52e72d00d1c3f81199000002"), 
  "email" : "John", 
  "name" : "john@gmail.com"
}
```

How can I fix this on a per `ObjectId` basis?

Comment: what do you mean "per object"? Is it just one document you want to update, many (defined), or all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this question [how can i update field with another field's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606657/how-can-i-update-field-with-another-fields-value).

It is tough to do in a single update query but you can use a javascript `forEach` loop:

```
db.item.find(conditions...).forEach( function (doc) {
  var email = doc.name;
  var name = doc.email

  doc.email = email; 
  doc.name = name      
  db.item.save(doc); 
});
```

You could maybe look at doing this in a one-liner like this;

```
doc.email = [doc.name, doc.name = doc.email][0];
```

But this is untested.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it with - db.User.find({name:/@/}).forEach(function (doc){ var email = doc.name; var name = doc.email; doc.email = email; doc.name = name; db.User.save(doc); });

Answer (score 9):

```
db.collection.update( { condition }, { $rename: { "email": "name" } } )
```

Don't forget change `name` field to something like `name_tmp` before this operation. Then rename `name_tmp` into `email`

Documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

Comment: Thanks, but only some records are wrong. Not all of them

Comment: Then, write your condition

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, I went with the above method, but yours actually looks easier in hindsight

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it works for me but I have had to set the option 'multi' to true.

`db.collection('collection').update({ condition }, { $rename: { "currentName": "newName" } }, { multi: true });`