# mongodb update a key to all documents using forEach

Tags: mongodb, loops, foreach

I want to update in `Mongo` the 'order' field to all of my documents so they will be 1..2..3..4....34.

After running this, they all have "order": "34".
What am I doing wrong?

```
var i = 1;
db.images.find().forEach(function() {
    db.images.update(
        {},
        { "$set": {"order": NumberInt(i)} },
        { multi: true }
    );
    i++;
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update field with another field's value in the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606657/update-field-with-another-fields-value-in-the-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`multi : true` means all documents matching the query will be updated. And your query is `{}`, which matches all the documents. So, basically you are updating the `order` of all the documents in every iteration.

Also, [`snapshot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) mode has to be enabled on the cursor to ensure that the same document isn't returned more than once.

You could try this:

```
var i = 1;
db.images.find().snapshot().forEach(function(image) {
    db.images.update(
        {"_id" : image._id},
        { "$set": {"order": NumberInt(i)} }
    );
    i++;
})
```

From a performance standpoint, it is better to use the bulk APIs. [bulkwrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db-collection-bulkwrite)

Comment: Thanks 4J41, this worked. I guess I wasn't so sure until now about how {"_id" : image._id} would help. Cheers.

Comment: Styvane can you explain what you're referring to?